# FactorySizeInGbUnits and MaxAllowedFactorySizeInGbUnits in Azure Data Factory Metrics

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Recently configured Data factory for the first time and wanted to understand the metrics being collected.
The two metrics that I am not able to understand are:

- **FactorySizeInGbUnits** - Is this the Gigabytes of data that Data Factory is transferring this very second or has transferred in totality so far?
- **MaxAllowedFactorySizeInGbUnits** - Is this a value we can set? For example, Maximum 100 Gigabytes of data can be transferred in a second?

I did look at the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftdatafactoryfactories) but the description isn't very clear (as shown below)
[image]

I have **configured the data factory in my lab, created pipeline, and performed a copy activity** and this is how the log looks:
[image]

These may be trivial metrics for experienced Data factory folks but is really confusing for a newbie like me. Please assist as I could not find any documentation that could explain the two in full depth with an example.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

FactorySizeInGbUnits -> Total size of the factory (pipelines + datasets + .....) rounded to next GB.

MaxAllowedFactorySizeInGbUnits -> Max allowed factory size.